# Scriptaculous two toggles at once

Tags: javascript, scriptaculous

How can I toggle an element to blind and fade at once?
I tried the code

```
   Event.observe(window,'load',function() {
    Event.observe($("delete"),'click',function() {
     Effect.toggle("entry","appear",{ duration: 2.0 });
     Effect.toggle("entry","blind",{ duration: 2.5 });
    });
   });
```

One will run, but not both.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Effect.Parallel](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/effect-parallel), although your example uses different durations, which I don't think it can do.